# How to extract out dates in a dd/mm/yyyy format from an unstructured string?

Tags: python, regex, named-entity-recognition

I have few strings like below :

```
'Thursday;60 days;Monday, days;the last two years;the six months;October 2017;March 2018;three days;Jan. 4;Last year;Dec. 21;'
```

expected result : `October 2017`

```
'January 7;30;39;24;46;1750;April 2017;April 30;February;'
```

expected result : `April 2017`

```
'Thursday;a day;another six days;the day;Tuesday;three days;mid-October;Wednesday;'
```

expected result : `mid-October`

I know the string is completely unstructured but can we have a python code to get the dates even from these ?

This is a part of a NER model where I am trying to extract the data entities.

I have tried a few methods but those were not even close to the result as string doesn't have a proper pattern

Comment: What's the logic?

Comment: Sorry,I am not sure what are you asking ?

Comment: atleast can we extract out the string part based on month name ?

Comment: For the first string, I get `['October 2017', 'March 2018', 'Jan. 4', 'Dec. 21']`. For the  second string, I get `['January 7', 'April 2017', 'April 30']` and no matches for the third one - using [datefinder](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder). Probably, you need to pre-process the text if you want to get something like `mid-october`, but you need to come up with specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`datefinder`](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder) with a regex to check for month names in the found date time strings:

```
import datefinder, re
from datetime import datetime

strs = ['Thursday;60 days;Monday, days;the last two years;the six months;October 2017;March 2018;three days;Jan. 4;Last year;Dec. 21;',
        'January 7;30;39;24;46;1750;April 2017;April 30;February;',
        'Thursday;a day;another six days;the day;Tuesday;three days;mid-October;Wednesday;']

day_of_week_rx = re.compile(r'(?:A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Dec(?:ember)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ly|ne|[ln]))|Ma(?:rch|[ry])|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Sep(?:tember)?)', re.I)
for s in strs:
    raw_dates = list(datefinder.find_dates(s, source=True))
    print([y for x,y in raw_dates if day_of_week_rx.search(y)])
```

Output:

```
['October 2017', 'March 2018', 'Jan. 4', 'Dec. 21']
['January 7', 'April 2017', 'April 30']
[]
```

Note that `mid-October` cannot be cast to a valid date time thus it is not extracted. You will need to apply some more specific regex like `re.search(r'\b(?:half|mid)-(?:A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Dec(?:ember)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ly|ne|[ln]))|Ma(?:rch|[ry])|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Sep(?:tember)?)', text)`.

The `(?:A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Dec(?:ember)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ly|ne|[ln]))|Ma(?:rch|[ry])|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Sep(?:tember)?)` matches English month full and abbreviated names.